# ElasticSearch: _template vs _index_template

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just realized that ES has a `_/_template` and a `_/_index_template`.

What are they for?

I was using code:

```
PutIndexTemplateRequest ngramTemplate = new PutIndexTemplateRequest("ngram-template")
    .patterns(Arrays.asList("resourcetable-*", "termconcept-*"))
    .settings(Settings.builder().put("index.max_ngram_diff", 50));
```

I didn't understand why my `ngram-template` didn't appear on `_/_index_template`.

After that, I was looking on `_/_template`.....

Which is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch switched from `_template` to `_index_template` in version 7.8.

`_template` is deprecated in 7.8 but still usable. if an indices match both lagacy template (_template) and Composable template (_index_template), elasticsearch will use Composable template.

the main difference betwean legacy and composable template is that legacy template is static and if you want change a field in all templates you must edit all templates but new _index_template is modular and for changing a setting in all templates you only need to change one component.